# Передать значение переменной в html с помощью ModelMap

Tags: java, html, spring

```
@GetMapping("/activate/{code}")
public String activate(ModelMap model, @PathVariable String code) {
    boolean isActivated = userService.activateUser(code);
    if (isActivated) {
        model.addAttribute("message", "User Successfully activated");
        System.out.println("Successfully");
    } else System.out.println("Activation code not found");
        model.addAttribute("message", "Activation code not found");
    return "verificationPage";
}
```

этот метод открывает страничку при клике на ссылку, в которой я хочу чтоб было значение атрибута message, я не добавлял сервлет и jsp, как можно отобразить это?
html-ка у меня пустая

Comment: Без TemplateEngine типа JSP не обойтись

Comment: а как мне его использовать?как изменить метод чтоб сработал сервлет и вызвался jsp?